# Java equivalent of Python's slice

Tags: java, python, java-8, java-stream

As you know - if not, glance at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) - Python's slice `:` notation does the following

```
[1:5] is equivalent to "from 1 to 5" (5 not included)
[1:] is equivalent to "1 to end"
a[-1] last item in the array
a[-2:] last two items in the array
a[:-2] everything except the last two items
```

I wonder that whether it is achieved by Java streams or something else in standard APIs similar *newer* since it is really useful sometimes.

Comment: It's too broad, and it's 5 different questions. It's unclear what you meant by "or something else".

Comment: nothing in the standard API like this, but I guess it's not that complicated to implement, but you will have to pass `:-2` part as a String and parse it

Comment: @Eugene how about `IntStream.range` for all the use cases? I mean not the syntax but functionality.

Comment: @nullpointer right, but you would still need to parse that input, it could be done in multiple other ways too, I guess

Comment: `-i` as an index in python is the same as `len(array)-i`, so is straightforward to implement with Java.

Comment: @Eugene I don't think OP is asking for that exact syntax (to be parsed). The question is about whether there's an equivalent in Java.

Comment: @sprinter as said earlier - *nothing in the standard API like this*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use the [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) API as follows :

[1:5] is equivalent to "from 1 to 5" (5 not included)

```
IntStream.range(1, 5).mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[1:] is equivalent to "1 to end"

```
IntStream.range(1, list.size()) // 0 not included
```

a[-1] last item in the array

```
IntStream.range(list.size() - 1, list.size()) // single item
```

a[-2:] last two items in the array

```
IntStream.range(list.size() - 2, list.size()) // notice two items
```

a[:-2] everything except the last two items

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 2)
```

***Notice*** the arguments are in the context `range​(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`.

Given a list of integer

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Completing any of the above to get the slice would be similar to specifying

```
List<Integer> slice = IntStream.range(1, 5).mapToObj(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // type 'Integer' could depend on type of list
```

---

You can also attain something similar using another API [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) with a similar construct, for e.g.

```
List<Integer> subList = list.subList(1, 5);
```

Both the above would output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is assuming that you're not looking for a parsing capability as well, such as `a[:-2]` to be parsed.

Comment: I think he also wants to get the values from the array, not only generated the values.

Comment: @Andrei yes, exactly

Comment: @snr Updated with what you might be looking for as an example.